# How do I create a ribbon bar in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

How do I create a ribbon bar in WPF, like in Office 2007?

Comment: I believe it will also be available in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: [WPF Toolkit adds Ribbon Control to .NET 3.5 SP1](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/10/WPF-Toolkit-adds-Ribbon-Control-to-NET-35-SP1.aspx)